# Disable default tooltip hint in VSCode not touching pycodestyle tips

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycodestyle

I met this problem after changing main IDE from PyCharm to VSCode.

On example, to see what's wrong here, i have to hover on underlined "def":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/no6eP.png

When i do this, i see this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRve5.png

**..and i must scroll down a huge amount of text to see, what pycodestyle are telling (expected 2 blank lines):** https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EJVm.png

(if i disable this https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpOjl.png, i would not see tooltips on hover at all: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGpBS.png)

**How can i see only pycodestyle tooltips, without this useless tons of default text?** Or maybe i should use another linter?

Comment: Can you tell me which linking generates the `function definition`? This is not available in my vscode

Comment: while trying to figure it out i sudennly solved the problem. It happend after disabled and enabled Python extension and linting in it, and selected pycodestyle as linter again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhy, after disabling and enabling Python extension, linting in it and selecting pycodestyle as linter again, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

you can see all pycodestyle warnings by another way, in warnings menu (Ctrl+Alt+M)